# Expect: How does one export the executing environmt to the runtime environment? (where keys are sent)

Tags: expect, autoexpect

I have tried the following:

```
set timeout -1
spawn $env(SHELL)
match_max 100000

send -- "ssh somewhere@addr"
expect "*"
for { set i 0 } { $i < [array size env] } { incr i } {
  send -- "echo env($i) = $env($i)"
  expect "*"
}
send -- "env > foo\r"
expect "*"
send -- "^D"
expect eof
```

The above fails with the following error:

```
no such variable
    (read trace on "::env(0)")
    invoked from within
"send -- "echo env($i) = env($i)""
    ("for" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"for { set i 0 } { $i < [array size env] } { incr i } {
    send -- "$::env($i)"
    expect "*"
}"
    (file "./script.exp" line 52)
```

I'll get around system issues by re-sourcing the `rc` files; I merely want to transport an unknown collection of vars (relative to the script) set by me to the remote execution environment.

Is this possible, I am unfamiliar with TCL (total beginner)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl [arrays](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/array) are more like a dictionary of keys and values than a list indexed by number. You can get the list of keys with `[array names env]` and traverse them with `foreach`:

```
foreach n [array names env] {
  send -- "echo env($n) = $env($n)\r"
  expect "\n"
}
```